# Confused with a step in solving differential equation $y'=ay-b.$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, derivatives

The way of solving this differential equation is by using substitution.

**2nd Method: Substitution:**

$$\dfrac{dy}{dt} = a y - b = u \implies \dfrac{du}{dy} = a \implies \dfrac{du}{a} = dy$$

Why does it become $\dfrac{du}{dy} = a$ after $\dfrac{dy}{dt} = ay-b = u$?

Comment: please be more clear and show research work.

Comment: Please take the time to typeset the question using [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). This is the least you can do to make it easy for us to help you

Comment: $u=ay-b\implies du/dy=a$

Comment: why we do the derivative with respect to y ?  no longer with t

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{dy}{dt} = a y - b $$
$$\dfrac{dy}{du}\dfrac {du}{dt} = a y - b $$
$$\dfrac{dy}{du}\dfrac {du}{dt} = u$$
We keep $\dfrac {du}{dt}$ but we need to express $\dfrac {dy}{du}$ with our new variables so:
$$\dfrac {dy}{du}=\dfrac {d((u+b)/a)}{du}=\dfrac 1a$$
So that the differential equation becomes:
$$\dfrac 1 a\dfrac {du}{dt}=u$$
$$\implies \dfrac {du}{dt}=a {u}$$